# How to return only one object in "where" statement with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

While creating a Rails app I have a common problem of finding a unique object in database that matches some conditions. And if there is more than one result, some kind of error needs to be triggered.
I do it like this right now:

```
results = ModelName.where(attr1: condition1, attr2: condition2)
raise "too many ModelName objects for condition" if results.count > 1
unique_result = results.first
```

But it seems too verbose for such a common task. It would be nice to only have to write something like this:

```
unique_result = ModelName.unique_where(attr1: condition1, attr2: condition2)
```

Is there a method that returns the record if it is unique or raises an exception if more than one record is found without manually extending ActiveRecord?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in method for this. Maybe it's easier to prevent duplicates in the first place using validations. Minor improvement: use `results.many?` instead of `results.count > 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there's no such built-in method, so I created an ActiveRecord::Relation extension for this purpose:

```
module ActiveRecordRelationExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def single_object!
    if self.many?
      raise "More than one instance of #{self.klass.name} returned"
    end
    return self.first
  end
end
```